# Sorting records from PostgreSQL with multiple decimal points (.)

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I have a list of records in PostgreSQL as follows, these are actually sections of various books
The records are generated in the below format.

```
1            
7.1        
6.2   
7.1    
7.4   
6.8.3   
6.8.2     
10     
1.1     
7.6     
6.1     
11    
8.3     
8.5     
1.1.2      
6.4      
6.6      
8.4      
1.1.6       
6.8.1        
7.7.1          
7.5          
7.3
```

I want to sort it like this

```
 1         
 1.1          
 1.1.2          
 1.1.6             
 6.2              
 6.4    
 6.5    
 6.6    
 6.7    
 6.8.1    
 6.8.2    
 6.8.3    
 7.2    
 7.3    
 7.4    
 7.5    
 7.6    
 7.7.1    
 7.7.2    
 8.3    
 8.4    
 8.5
 10
```

It's a varchar column so i have tried using what listed here.
[Sorting records from Oracle with multiple decimal points (.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020116/sorting-records-from-oracle-with-multiple-decimal-points)

```
select * from tbl_wo_kitting where wo_project_id = 1000033
ORDER BY to_number(regexp_substr(line_no, '[^.]+', 1, 1)) NULLS FIRST
```

It keeps saying invalid function name regexp_substr.
What are the functions to sort that way?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Postgresql. Sorry selected the wrong flag. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by converting the string to an integer array, then sort on the array:

```
select * 
from tbl_wo_kitting 
where wo_project_id = 1000033
ORDER BY (string_to_array(line_no, '.'))::int[]
```

Note that this will fail if there are values that cannot be converted to numbers in the `line_no_` column.

Comment: Thank you so much. that actually work. I have to convert the varchar value first then sort it using ORDER BY (string_to_array(line_no, '.'))::int[]